# Is there a free/web-based game that requires knowledge of SQL to win?

Tags: learning

Looking for an alternative way of teaching SQL, and wondering if there is a free/web-based game that requires knowledge of SQL to win. If possible, the game should not only be fun, but also track how much SQL the player knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to win via SQL if you'll get up on the top of [rating](http://www.sql-ex.ru/rating.php).
Every SQL exercise solved shall put up you in rating.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a gamified SQL learning tool, **but** I'll recommend [The Manga Guide To Databases](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271905) as a way to cut through the boredom factor. It's a fast read, even for retro-technical managers, and does a quick survey of how to design and use a DB.

Comment: +1 Yes, I've seen a few of the The Manga Guides, including the guide to databases; it's okay - only 20% of the book appears to be on SQL, and 50% of that amount appears to read as a "normal" book on SQL; that said, it's got high-rating on Amazon, though I don't by into Amazon rating as much as I once did. The nearest I know to a free/web-based game is [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net) - though it's not a game, but would fit the format of a game; meaning it's not gamified, but you've got a series of mini-quizes to take.